# Deleting a record/multiple records with a checkbox(PHP/MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Please can someone help me with this. I'm a total noob with php/mysql/stackoverflow.

I'm trying to delete a record from a mysql database - this is my code so far....

```
//Includes db connect file


// Display the student(s) within the html table
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

 {
echo "<tr><td align='centre' bgcolor='#693'><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value=' $rows'Delete record?'>";
echo "<td> $row[studentid] </td> <td> $row[password] </td>";
echo "<td> $row[dob] </td><td> $row[firstname] </td>";
echo "<td> $row[lastname] </td><td> $row[house] </td>";
echo "<td> $row[town] </td><td> $row[county] </td>";
echo "<td> $row[country] </td><td> $row[postcode] </td>";
}echo "</table>";

echo "<tr><td colspan='11' align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><input name='delete' type='submit' id='delete' value='Delete selected student(s)'></td>";
echo "</tr>";

?>

<?php


if($_POST['delete']) // from button name="delete"
 {
    $checkbox = $_POST['checked'];
    $countCheck = count($_POST['checked']);

    for($i=0;$i<$countCheck;$i++) {
        $del_id = $checkbox[$i];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM student WHERE  = $del_id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Even if your request is urgent,  you shouldn't overemphasize it so much. The people here are volunteers for the most part, so this kind of subject actually turns more people off from offering you help.

Comment: You are wide open to SQL injection at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM student WHERE  = $del_id";
```

`WHERE <something> = $del_id`, you're missing the `<something>`, which presumably should be `id`.

Also, you probably want to research "[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)", "[Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)" and "[Input Sanitization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_input_and_output_handling)", since your code is currently not sanitizing inputs/outputs or protecting against SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM student WHERE  id= %d";
$sql = sprintf($sql,(int)$del_id);
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Now that should work, unless you have other errors

Comment: Unless $del_id isn't set to begin with. This presumes the OP's set up their HTML form properly and is referring to the right form field.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to note:

1. Your delete should before before the output. I say this because even if a delete is successful, it will show up once more before the delete actually triggers, leaving you with a "Ghost" entry.
2. Make sure to sanitize the input from a user when dealing with a database--[`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) has a specific purpose, especially if you're not using an ADO. Alternatively you can use something like `$delete_id = (int)$checkbox[$i]` to make sure it's an integer value.
3. Your delete needs to reference which column in your where clause the delete pertains to. Usually this is the primary key of the table. Make sure to change the checkbox's value to something like `$row['id']` (or whatever the key) and then re-reference that column in your `DELETE FROM student WHERE <column> = <checkbox_value>)`

Answer (score 0):

[LIVE DEMO](http://www.crackerworld.in/2014/01/delete-multiple-rows.html)

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
$check=$_POST['check'];
$count=count($check);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$del_id = $check[$i];
$delete=mysql_query("delete from emp where id='$del_id'") or die(mysql_error());
}
if($delete){ $msg2="Successfully Deleted!!";}

}
```